# "Mean looking" meaning?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context

What does it mean for "Mean looking" in this sentence?

"Mean looking" means that as soon as you see it you think, "Jeez! I won't be able to finish that."

It's for food, but I'm not sure does it mean the food looks bad? Not in good appearance?

Comment: If something is 'mean looking', it is scary in some way. the food could be good, but the portion might be very large, more than you can eat. If it looked bad (rotten or disgusting) you would not even start to eat it, and the speaker thinks they will start it, but maybe not finish.

Comment: Normally, anything described as "mean-looking" would be a *person*, or at least "conscious entity". Imho, it's inherently "quirky, facetious" to apply this label to something like a plate of food. Unless what you're looking at is obviously "an animal" of some kind, such as a large-clawed lobster that might still look "mean" even after being boiled to death and served up in a restaurant! :)

Comment: ...it's still seriously metaphoric, but I wouldn't say [***an intimidating plateful***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+intimidating+plateful%22) was inherently "quirky", so long as the *specific* intended sense was ***intimidatingly large***. I think it *would* be deliberately quirky if anything other than the size of the portion was being referenced, though.

Comment: It could be reasonable sized dish with (e.g.) a lot of hot peppers visible.

Comment: It would also make more sense if, as @FumbleFingers writes it, the phrase was hyphenated. Otherwise, it makes "mean" look like a noun, which it isn't.